# Is select() with NULL timeout lighter than select() with timeout?

Tags: c, select

I would like to know if that code:

```
select(fd,..., NULL);
```

is less CPU consuming than that one:

```
struct timeval tv;
tv.tv_sec = X;
tv_tv_usec = Y;
select(fd,..., &tv);
```

and why. Thank you.

EDIT: I'm asking about one single call. It's a sys call, so it's system dependent and it's up to the system to unblock the select()ing program. So, for the system, is more CPU consuming to accomplish to a select with or without timeout?

Comment: There is probably a tiny penalty required to queue a signal if no IO is pending and dequeue it when IO arrives.  This penalty is dwarfed by the cost of IO itself.  As always, try it both ways and benchmark. The results will be extremely system-dependent and could even vary with load conditions on the same system.

Comment: You can use `strace ./yourprogram` to find out by yourself.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by lighter... the NULL value just won't return, so that loop won't spin, it seems totally irrelevant to me... it if just sleeps until something happens...

Answer (score 0):

Neither is "lighter". `select` is a system call and will instruct the OS to wake up your task when either an event occurs on one of the watched file descriptors or (if supplied) a timeout occurs. `select`ing with a `NULL` timeout will select indefinitely until a watched file descriptor event occurs of the process is interrupted in another way.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly:

```
 while (select(..., NULL) == 0) { /* ... */ }
```

is lighter than:

```
 while (select(..., tv) == 0) { /* ... */ }
```

where the time in tv is small, otherwise the difference is likely too small to be noticed.

Comment: Yes, of course, but I'm talking about the single call of select(), not in a loop.

Comment: If you are only doing '1' of something, then worrying about optimizing it is almost assuredly premature.

Comment: With a timeout, select has to go to the trouble of setting up the timeout, that takes a small but non-zero amount of time.  Definitely small as compared with the overhead of making the syscall in the first place (which is why the second loop in my example could be noticeably heavier if the timeout was small because that would means lots more syscalls than the top example).